# How to maintain same index for dictonary from dataframe

Tags: python

When I tried to run this code:

```
X_test = df.values 
df_new = ks.DataFrame(X_test, columns = ['Sales','T_Year','T_Month','T_Week','T_Day','T_Hour'])
```

I am getting new index for `df_new` data frame which is not the same has `df`.

I tried changing the code below to retain index for dictionary. However it gives an error:

```
X_test = df.values(index=df.index)
```

> 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable.

Is there a way to maintain an index for `df_new` which are the same has `df` dataframe?

[image]

Comment: Please provide more information. What is ks? Please show your imports and an example.

Comment: import databricks.koalas as ks

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: numpy.ndarray' object is not callable when calling this code X_test = df.values(index=df.index)

Comment: got it, writing my answer

Comment: `df_new.index = df.index` perhaps?

Comment: `df_new.set_index(df.index)` probably works, right?

Comment: getting this error  for df_new.set_index(df.index) . The method `pd.Index.__iter__()` is not implemented. If you want to collect your data as an NumPy array, use 'to_numpy()' instead.

Answer (score 0):

DataFrames have a [`set_index()`](https://koalas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/api/databricks.koalas.DataFrame.set_index.html) method in order to manually set the "index column". Koalas in particular accepts as main argument:

> keys: label or array-like or list of labels/arrays
> This parameter can be either a single column key, a single array of the same length as the calling DataFrame, or a list containing an arbitrary combination of column keys and arrays. Here, “array” encompasses Series, Index and np.ndarray.

By that, you can pass the `Index` object of your original df:

```py
X_test = df.values 
df_new = ks.DataFrame(X_test, columns = ['Sales','T_Year','T_Month','T_Week','T_Day','T_Hour'])  

df_new = df_new.set_index(df.index)
```

---

Now about the line you are getting an error:

```
X_test = df.values(index=df.index)
```

The errors arise due to the fact that you are kind of confusing `numpy` arrays with `pandas` DataFrames.
When you call `df.values` of a DataFrame `df`, this returns a `np.ndarray` object with all the dataframe values *without the index*.
This is not a function, so you cannot "call it" by writing `(index=df.index)`.
Numpy arrays don't have custom indixes, they are just arrays. Your `df_new` only cares about that, and you can set it as I showed above.

---

Disclaimer: I wasn't able to install `koalas` for this answer, so this is only tested in pandas Dataframes. If koalas does support pandas' interface completely, that should work.

Comment: df_new = df_new.set_index(df.index) seems this does not work in koalas dataframe getting the same error

Comment: How about `df_new = df_new.set_index(df.index.values)`  or `df_new = df_new.set_index(df.index.to_numpy())`? Both should be the same.